# Processing data from XML tags in python

Tags: python, xml, django, lxml

I am trying to extract data from an XML document using python.

The tool I'm currently trying with and seems like it is a stable choice is [lxml](http://lxml.de/).

The issue I'm having is that the tutorials and questions I have came across all assume the format of the XML document is as follows:

```
<note> 
   <to>Tove</to> 
   <from>Jani</from> 
   <heading>Reminder</heading> 
   <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body> 
</note>
```

With the values inside the XML tags.

However - the document I am trying to extract from has values inside elements of the tags, like so:

```
<note> 
   <to id="16" name="Tove"/>
   <from id="341" name"Jani"/> 
   <heading id="1" name="Reminder"/> 
   <body id="2" name="Don't forget me this weekend!"/> 
</note>
```

The way I have tried doing this in LXML is this:

```
xml_file = lxml.etree.parse("test.xml")

notes = xml_file.xpath("//note")

for note in notes:
    note_id = note.find("id").text
    print note_id
```

This just returns "None"

I have now found that the `.text` is what gets data from inside the XML tags - However I simply can't find how to get the data from the elements shown above.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the attributes you should use an **attrib**:

```
xml_file = lxml.etree.parse("test.xml")

notes = xml_file.xpath("//note")

for note in notes:
    print [ x.attrib for x in note.getchildren() ]
```

More reading: http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elements-carry-attributes-as-a-dict

Comment: I am trying this and I get the error - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrib' -

Comment: Right, I made mistake - fixed the code how to get attributes for tag "to".

Comment: Actually I have made another edit - you can iterate over children using getchildren and then get attributes.

Comment: Ah brilliant that has worked - You should leave the original edit to your answer as well for anyone that may stumble upon this post as that was ver helpful. as is this edit with the getchildren function. +1